# Updating table data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the below SQL statement. What I am trying to do is add two values based on conditions. So if `@IsUCMPresent` is 1 then I should get 75*70 but if `@IsEVMPresent` is also present I should be getting (75 * 70) + (75 * 8)

```
  SET @IsEVMPresent = 1
  SET @IsUCMPresent = 1

  UPDATE #MainData
  SET OneTimeExpense = (CASE WHEN @IsUCMPresent = 1 THEN 75 * 70 END) +
                       (CASE WHEN @IsEVMPresent = 1 THEN 75 * 8 END)
  WHERE ItemId = 'ECS' OR ItemId = 'UCM'
```

The issue is that if `@IsUCMPresent = 1` is true then I get the sum just fine but if only `@IsEVMPresent = 1` is true then I don't get 75 * 8

Comment: And what problem do you have?

Comment: It's not returning anything

Comment: What about if IsUCMPresent = 0 but IsEVMPresent = 1.  What equation should you be getting then?

Comment: I edited my question to show the exact problem I am having and this is what the exact problem is if IsUCMPresent = 0 but IsEVMPresent = 1 i should still be getting 75 * 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an else clause to your case statements:

```
UPDATE #MainData
    SET   
    OneTimeExpense  = (Case When @IsUCMPresent = 1  Then 75 * 70 Else 0 End) +
                      (Case When @IsEVMPresent = 1  Then 75 * 8  Else 0 End)
Where ItemId IN('ECS','UCM')
```

Without them it will return null and Sql cannot add a number and null.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for..Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

In both CASEs you should specify `ELSE 0` otherwise the CASE will give you NULL and will do nothing.